# How explicit must you be when calling a constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this class

```
struct foo
{
    explicit foo(const std::uint32_t& x, const std::uint32_t& y);
};
```

and a method

```
int main()
{
    std::int32_t x = -1;
    std::int32_t y = -1;
    foo f(x, y);
}
```

On my compiler (MSVC2012), this compiles and runs with the values `x` and `y` wrapped around to unsigned types. I was not expecting this, but was expecting a compile error due to mismatched types.

What am I missing?

Comment: Mismatched types will typically throw compiler *warnings* but not *errors*. These warnings can include `signed`/`unsigned` mismatch and loss of precision (`double` --> `float`)

Comment: But should this not even *compile* due to references being passed? Or is an implicit reference cast permitted? (I'm aware that `explicit` only guards against brace initialisation).

Comment: There are standard conversions between integral types. The call will create temporaries via a standard conversion and bind `const` references to them.

Comment: So would it "work" too if `x` and `y` were `double` types in `main()`?

Comment: Explicit constructors have to be called *explicitly*. For example, `void bar(foo); bar({0, 0});` should be rejected.

Comment: Would I be OK if I dropped the `const` then? That means that an anonymous temporary could **not** be created.

Comment: Interestingly, `foo f{x, y};` will still compile; brace-initialization only catches the narrowing conversion when initializing the individual parameters: `foo f{{x}, {y}};`

Comment: Hmm... VS2013 only complains about that conversion at `/Wall`: http://rextester.com/PBMG72917

Comment: It's a headache. The class is actually a matrix class and I can wave goodbye to my process when trying to create a matrix with size (-1, -1)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're out of luck, the standard does allow implicit conversion of signed to unsigned via the creation of an anonymous temporary for an argument passed by constant reference.

(Note this is not true for a non-constant reference).

If you're using C++11, the best thing to do is to delete the constructor using

```
foo(const std::int32_t& x, const std::int32_t& y) = delete;
```

Pre C++11 you could make this constructor `private` and not *define* it. Rather like the old-fashioned not-copyable idioms.

MSVC2012 is a sort of half-way house C++03 / C++11 compiler. It implements some C++11 features but not others. Unfortunately deletion of constructors is one of the features it does **not** support so the `private`isation approach is the best method available to you.

Comment: Of course it does. That's why I'm your boss ;-). +1 for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should use the new brace-initialization syntax `foo f{x, y}` that will at least emit a warning. After that you can configure your compiler to treat warnings as errors and handle them accordingly, as good code should usually get rid of warnings too (because if you **wanted** the conversion to happen, you should have used an **explicit cast**).

Answer (score 0):

`explicit` does not prevent implicit conversion with the constructor arguments (which clearly takes place here when binding the references); it prevents implicit construction.

```
void bar(foo);
int main()
{
   foo f({0, 0}); // doesn't matter that the arguments are implicitly converted

   bar({0, 0});   // error - implicit conversion required here to pass a foo
   bar(f);        // crucially, ok because argument requires no conv. construction
}
```